# Specify download location in webdrivermanager java

Tags: webdriver-manager, webdrivermanager-java

How can i specify the download location of the chromedriver in webdrivermanager? Im using Java.

At the moment its downloading to ~\cache\selenium\chromedriver\

im using webdrivermanger version 5.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `wd.cachePath` property described in the documentation: https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/#advanced-configuration

Answer (score 2):

WebDriverManager.globalConfig().setCachePath("Path");

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This has already been mentioned in other answer. When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers